# Pentaho Kettle (Data Intergration) MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pentaho

I'm using kettle v5.2 which support the aggregation pipleline in MongoDB 
when using MongoDB input the query works for small data set but I need to use option
allowDiskUse to the query can't figure how to add this in pentaho 
while I tested this option in mongo shell and it's working as expected

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/MongoDB+Input#MongoDBInput-queryaggpipeline